# What does it mean for a MOSFET to be fabricated in a 0.4nm (or any length) process?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

It was mentioned in a problem where the drain current was supposed to be found with the given parameters. There was channel length modulation. The problem was solved seemingly without taking this 0.4nm into account.

I know it's not the channel length or width because they were given to be different numbers.

I couldn't find what this means after vigorous googling for half an hour, all that comes up is similar problems that also ignore this value.

Edit: If it's the feature size (see 1st comment), which I looked up to find that it's the minimum channel length, how would that affect the operating point? We also used Lmin values in place of L in some problems so they seemed to be the same. What are the cases this value would be used as the channel length to find drain current?

Comment: Something like this did not come up? https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-the-meaning-of-feature-size?share=1 Anyway, I have the feeling that nowadays it's more marketing than technology.

Comment: Thanks, just learning it's called feature size is very helpful.

Comment: That is not a realistic feature size, though. 0.4nm. There is no 0.4nm process as far as I know/understand.

Comment: I have heard of nothing under 10nm and right now 14nm has high yields. We are at the limit of xUV lithography using diamond lenses. For now.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when a CMOS manufacturing process is described as having a certain length, such as "a 14 nm process", they mean that the transistor physical gate length (the "drawn length") is 14 nm. Usually, this is also the smallest manufacturable feature in the process...wiring, contacts, vias, and implants will be larger.

The source and drain implants may diffuse a bit so that they spread under the physical gate and make the electrical gate length smaller than the physical gate length. I suppose there are also electrical effects that could come into play here. However, if the physical gate length is large compared to the expected deviations in gate length then we would just use the drawn gate length as the minimum gate length.

Comment: Electron beams are used to "undercut" certain layers to improve the breakdown voltage for such tiny dimensions. I have heard of nothing under 10nm and right now 14nm has high yields. We are at the limit of xUV lithography using diamond lenses. For now.